# Insert fields into SQL Server from visual web developer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am working in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition. I have a series of 6 drop down lists generated from my SQL Server 2008 database. I also have a grid view that displays the rows in the database based on two of the drop down list selections.

This is effective but I need to move one step beyond. Using the same six drop down lists, I need to update the table. The primary key is actually the six columns that are on the web page.

Ideally, I would like to have the user select the information from the drop down lists and hit a button that will insert the rows into the database. Then refresh the grid view to confirm the insert.

I have tried to use the details view per a tutorial that I had used to create the grid view.

So my ultimate question is how do I attach the SQL `INSERT` statement to a button and have the button do both the insert into the database and refresh the grid view?

Comment: Why don't you call a `stored-procedure` on the button click event and if it success, reload the grid?? If you need more info please have a look [How to call SQL Server stored procedures in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306574)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SQL datasource, then on button_click event pass in

```
SQLDataSource1.InsertParameters["ParameterName"].DefaultValue = +yourvalue+;
 //use this command to pass in all your values
try 
{
SQLDataSource1.Insert();
GridView1.DataBind();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
// Deal with the exception if encountered here.
}
```

Comment: My datasource is called DataMaster.  It is the same datasource that I use for the GridView.  I entered the button update in the asp.cs with the following  
Line 31:         protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 32:         {
Line 33:             DataMaster.InsertParameters["Ref"].DefaultValue = dlRef.SelectedValue;

 
There are additional parameters however I get the following error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  I also tried using other values related to the dlRef(drop down list for parameter REF

Comment: have u enabled autopostback on the dropdown lists ? because your object dl.ref is returning a null value to your code from the selectedvalue. If its on, make a query test to your DATAMASTER by putting a label on the page and setting the value

Comment: label1.text = dlRef.SelectedValue; and check if the value is changing when u select the different value from the dropdownlist. If it doesnt then autopostback is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to need to make a separate function for populating the grid,  Let the name of function is " POPULATEGRIDVIEW()".. in this function you will write the code to bind a GridView ... After that generate Button1_Clik Event then write the code of insert query , like I am giving a example

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query="insert into emp values('"+ddl1.text+"','"+ddl2.text+"') ";
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con);
    con.Open();
    if((cmd.ExecuteNonQuery)==True)
    {
        POPULATEGRIDVIEW();
    }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Some Problem Occure in Insertion ")
   }
}
```

Try It....